# Difference between entities in Design.Entities and SkectchManager.Entities

Tags: entities, eyeshot

I am new to using Eyeshot from devDept and as I read through the documentation and examples one of the things that I have noticed is that some of the examples add entities to the Design.Entities collection and some other examples add entities to the SketchManager Entities collection. Can someone explain what is the difference between those two collections? When is applicable to add entities to either one of them? Do all entities in the SketchManager are also present on the Design.Entities collection, but not the opposite?

The examples in Eyeshot are great but the documentation not so much.
I do understand that Eyeshot is an advanced package and requires 3D modeling knowledge but as a developer just starting to learn about eyeshot, I am finding that the documentation could be more helpful to explain the basic concepts on how to use Eyeshot's API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SketchEntities` are related to parametric sketches, while `Entities` are standard drawing entities. Usually, you don't use SketchEntities directly but through `SketchManager`. [Here](https://youtu.be/ypOW8KMmbPE), you can see the `SketchManager` in action.

If you need parametric sketches to draw your geometry you'll be using SketEntities indirectly, otherwise, you'll use standard `Entities`.